# Can you make custom buttons and menus using windows gdi?

Tags: c++, gdi

Like create a file menu with a picture using gdi? Are menus in windows forms just an animation with an event?

Comment: No, a menu is a window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Can you make custom buttons and menus using windows gdi? Like create a file menu with a picture using gdi?

You *can* do this, but I don't understand why you would want to. All of the Windows GDI functions are documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd145203.aspx). There are a whole bunch of them, you'll need to figure out which ones to call depending on what you want to accomplish.

For example, to draw a picture, you will need to load the bitmap resource from somewhere (like a file on disk or your application's embedded resources) using the `LoadImage` function, and then draw that bitmap into a screen device context using the `BitBlt` function or one of its close relatives. Handling the `WM_PAINT` message is the preferred way to get a device context that you can draw into.

From your question, it appears that you don't have more than a basic understanding of how GDI works. That's going to be a real problem because what you've proposed here is a fairly massive undertaking. You're essentially reimplementing all of the Windows user interface. If you absolutely must proceed, I recommend taking some time first to learn the basics of drawing with GDI. Maybe pick up a book, like Charles Petzold's classic [Programming Windows, 5th Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/157231995X) and/or Feng Yuan's excellent [Windows Graphics Programming: Win32 GDI and DirectDraw](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0130869856) (although they've both been out of print for a long while; you'll need to seek out used copies).

> Are menus in windows forms just an animation with an event?

Like Hans's comment says, no, menus are actually windows. But the operating system itself takes care of all the details for you, creating the menu, displaying your items, performing the animation, etc. All you have to do is use the [menu-related API functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468865.aspx). It's really very simple and it works well.

You can create your own menus by creating the window yourself and applying your own animation. But again, I ask: why?